# I'm getting an error when scraping real-time data while pulling it into mysql database with python (TypeError: not enough arguments for format string)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

i have links.csv file and i use pd.read_csv to get this links one by one. My csv file looks something like this: https://im.ge/i/1i38PY

Except fourth link, i can scrap all infos from the links that took me to the site in real time based by my first codes. Datas directly saves in mysql CARFINAL table like this : https://im.ge/i/1igBaG

The error I got for the fourth link is this-> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string /////
print(df) looks like this -> https://im.ge/i/1i8tgT

this is my first codes at the bottom;

```
    cursor = scrap_db.cursor()

    
    # Drop table as per requirement
    # cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CARFINAL')

    # Create table as per requirement

    sql = """CREATE TABLE CARFINAL(
        brand VARCHAR(120),
        model VARCHAR(120),
        model_version VARCHAR(120),
        location VARCHAR(60),
        price VARCHAR(80),
        dealer VARCHAR(60),
        contact_name VARCHAR(60),
        tel_number VARCHAR(50),
        mileage VARCHAR(50),
        gearbox VARCHAR(60),
        first_registration VARCHAR(30),
        fuel_type VARCHAR(120),
        power VARCHAR(60),
        seller VARCHAR(60),
        body_type VARCHAR(30),
        type VARCHAR(10),
        drivetrain VARCHAR(10),
        seats int(11),
        doors int(11),
        country_version VARCHAR(20),
        offer_number VARCHAR(20),
        model_code int(11),
        production_date int(11),
        general_inspection int(11),
        previous_owner int(11),
        full_service_history VARCHAR(10),
        non_smoker_vehicle VARCHAR(10),
        engine_size VARCHAR(20),
        gears VARCHAR(10),
        cylinders VARCHAR(10),
        fuel_consumption VARCHAR(60),
        CO2_emissions VARCHAR(30),
        energy_efficiency_class VARCHAR(10),
        CO2_efficiency VARCHAR(80),
        emission_class VARCHAR(20),
        emissions_sticker VARCHAR(10),
        colour_and_upholstery VARCHAR(60),
        all_equipment VARCHAR(300),
        vehicle_description VARCHAR(400),
        car_picture_link VARCHAR(200),
        link VARCHAR(200)
        )"""

    cursor.execute(sql)
    
    
    
    #Save data to the table

    #scrap_db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='****',database='autoscout',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                                                
    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO CARFINAL
        (brand,
        model,
        model_version,
        location,
        price,
        dealer,
        contact_name,
        tel_number,
        mileage,
        gearbox,
        first_registration,
        fuel_type,
        power,
        seller,
        body_type,
        type,
        drivetrain,
        seats,
        doors,
        country_version,
        offer_number,
        model_code,
        production_date,
        general_inspection,
        previous_owner,
        full_service_history,
        non_smoker_vehicle,
        engine_size,
        gears,
        cylinders,
        fuel_consumption,
        CO2_emissions,
        energy_efficiency_class,
        CO2_efficiency,
        emission_class,
        emissions_sticker,
        colour_and_upholstery,
        all_equipment,
        vehicle_description,
        car_picture_link,
        link
        )
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """
        for row_count in range(0, df.shape[0]): # range(0,1) 
            chunk = df.iloc[row_count:row_count + 1,:].values.tolist()    
        tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in chunk)
            
        cursor = scrap_db.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, tuple_of_tuples) 
        scrap_db.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into CARFINAL table")
        scrap_db.close()

len_of_links = len(make_model_ads_data_latest)
number = np.arange(4,5)
j = 0
for i in tqdm(number):
    ad_link = make_model_ads_data_latest['ad_link'][i]
    #ad_link = make_model_ads_data_latest['ad_link'][i+1] #BAK
    
    if ad_link not in make_model_ads_data['link'].values:
        data = get_ad_data(ad_link = ad_link, sleep_time = 0)
        j = j + 1
        
print("scraped ", j, " new ads")
```

By the way if i use my 2. codes; it works just for the fourth link. i have just replaced my firts codes to something like this ; .....

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE CAR2(
        brand VARCHAR(120),
        model VARCHAR(120),
        model_version VARCHAR(120),
        location VARCHAR(60),
        price VARCHAR(80),
        dealer VARCHAR(60),
        contact_name VARCHAR(60),
        tel_number VARCHAR(50),
        mileage VARCHAR(50),
        gearbox VARCHAR(60),
        first_registration VARCHAR(30),
        fuel_type VARCHAR(120),
        power VARCHAR(60),
        seller VARCHAR(60),
        body_type VARCHAR(30),
        type VARCHAR(10),
        seats int(11),
        doors int(11),
        country_version VARCHAR(20),
        model_code  VARCHAR(20),
        engine_size VARCHAR(20),
        colour_and_upholstery VARCHAR(30),
        all_equipment VARCHAR(300),
        vehicle_description VARCHAR(400),
        car_picture_link VARCHAR(200),
        link VARCHAR(200)
        )"""

    cursor.execute(sql)
    
    
    
    #Save data to the table

    #scrap_db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='1234',database='autoscout',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                                                
    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO CAR2
        (brand,
        model,
        model_version,
        location,
        price,
        dealer,
        contact_name,
        tel_number,
        mileage,
        gearbox,
        first_registration,
        fuel_type,
        power,
        seller,
        body_type,
        type,
        seats,
        doors,
        country_version,  
        model_code,
        engine_size,
        colour_and_upholstery,
        all_equipment,
        vehicle_description,
        car_picture_link,
        link
        )
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """
```

But i don't want to change the structure everytime when i scrape

i got stuck. please help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correct, the issue is with a row that has less items. This row(s) can be padded, using for example pd.fillna or so?

In other words, make sure your tuple is always of the desired size. Another option is to add [''] * (desired_len - act_len), or so.